# clang vs gcc: how to inspect multiple inheritance second-parent relationships in clang

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, multiple-inheritance

Is there a "best-practice" way to inspect (at compile-time) non-first-parent relationships in multiple-inheritance relationships? I illustrate my problem with an example below:

This code is a method that allows for inspection of non-first-parent relationships in multiple inheritance, by using a void pointer comparison trick that works in GCC (6.3 and below: 7.1 and above do not allow it) but not in clang (5.0.0):

```
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wreinterpret-base-class"

#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>

struct Grandparent {
    int thing = 1;
    virtual void foo() {};
};

struct Parent1 : Grandparent {
    int thing = 2;
};

struct Parent2 : Grandparent {
    int thing = 3;
};

struct MIChild : public Parent1, public Parent2 {
    int thing = 4;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
class IsSameVoidPtr
{
    static constexpr T1* _p = nullptr;
    static constexpr bool Castable(std::true_type)
    {
        return static_cast<void*>(_p + 1) == static_cast<void*>(static_cast<T2*>(_p + 1));
    }
    static constexpr bool Castable(std::false_type) { return false; }
public:
    static constexpr bool value = Castable(std::integral_constant<bool,
        std::is_base_of<T1, T2>{} || std::is_base_of<T2, T1>{}>{});
};

int main() {
    MIChild test;
    Grandparent* gp_ptr = reinterpret_cast<Grandparent*>(&test);
    Parent1* p1_ptr = reinterpret_cast<Parent1*>(&test);
    Parent2* p2_ptr = reinterpret_cast<Parent2*>(&test);
    MIChild* ch_ptr = &test;
    static_assert(IsSameVoidPtr<Parent1, Grandparent>::value == true, "Failed P1 to G test");
    static_assert(IsSameVoidPtr<Parent2, Grandparent>::value == true, "Failed P2 to G test");
    static_assert(IsSameVoidPtr<Parent1, Parent2>::value == false, "Failed P1 to P2 test");
    static_assert(IsSameVoidPtr<MIChild, Parent1>::value == true, "Failed C to P1 test");
    static_assert(IsSameVoidPtr<MIChild, Parent2>::value == false, "Failed C to P2 test");
}
```

GCC compiles this and it works as intended. It correctly sees that the second parent has a different void pointer from the child as well as the first parent.

However, clang will not permit arithmetic on the null pointer, and this leads to a whole chain of errors (I show the first instance of the errors, the others are all similar):

```
32 : <source>:32:27: error: constexpr variable 'value' must be initialized by a constant expression
    static constexpr bool value = Castable(std::integral_constant<bool,
                          ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
42 : <source>:42:19: note: in instantiation of template class 'IsSameVoidPtr<Parent1, Grandparent>' requested here
    static_assert(IsSameVoidPtr<Parent1, Grandparent>::value == true, "Failed P1 to G test");
                  ^
28 : <source>:28:38: note: cannot perform pointer arithmetic on null pointer
        return static_cast<void*>(_p + 1) == static_cast<void*>(static_cast<T2*>(_p + 1));
                                     ^
32 : <source>:32:35: note: in call to 'Castable({})'
    static constexpr bool value = Castable(std::integral_constant<bool,
                                  ^
```

Comment: To my knowledge expression `_p + 1` is not a constant expression and the compilers are right they forbid it... See: [\[expr.const\]/2.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.6)

Comment: just to clarify, do you want a trait class template detecting all possible ambiguous subclass-to-superclass pointer conversions ?

Comment: The template should be able to (at compile time) reject the non-first-parent case as "false", and the first-parent case as "true". std::is_base_of<> will count the non-first-parent case as a valid case.

Comment: in >=c++11, you can write such a thing for aggregate types; regarding the general case, I'd bet it's not possible

Comment: Thank you. Well, I'll leave it up here and see if we get lucky. Or maybe someone who knows the C++ standard very well could explain why it would not be standard-compliant. It does seem to me that this information should be available at compile time.